# Unit testing the MS AJAX Toolkit HTML editor

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, selenium, ajaxcontroltoolkit, watin

Is it possible to unit test the MS AJAX Control Toolkit's [HTML Editor](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/HTMLEditor/HTMLEditor.aspx)? I've tried [Watin](http://watin.sourceforge.net/), WebAii and Selenium without any success...

### Watin

I can find the textbox related to the control but I get an exception trying to access it:

```
using (Browser ie = new IE()) {
    ie.GoTo(testUri);
    Assert.IsTrue(ie.ContainsText("Expected text"));

    var textBox = ie.TextField(Find.ById(id => id.Contains("Editor")));
    textBox.TypeText("testing 123");
}
```

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Can't move focus to the control
>   because it is invisible, not enabled,
>   or of a type that does not accept the
>   focus.

### Selenium

I tried the Selenium IDE also without any success. When I loaded [ASP.net's sample page](http://asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/HTMLEditor/HTMLEditor.aspx), typed some text into the editor and clicked the "Submit" button here is the test case it made:

```
[Test]
public void TheUntitledTest() {
    selenium.Open("/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/HTMLEditor/HTMLEditor.aspx");
    // Text was typed at this point
    selenium.Click("ctl00_SampleContent_submit");
}
```

Here is the log messages from rerunning the recorded actions in the Selenium IDE:

> [info] Executing: |open | /AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/HTMLEditor/HTMLEditor.aspx | |
>
> [info] Executing: |click | ctl00_SampleContent_submit | |

Answer (score 1):

Looking the control it is an IFrame where the editor is actually an editable body

```
<body contentEditable="true">
```

You should be able to update the inner text with javascript using the

```
IE.Frame(Find.BySrc(frameSrc)).Eval( ... javascript goes here ... );
```

command in watiN then click the button.

Another approach would be to do a mouse move, then click, then send keys.