# How to enter text in AJAX HTML Editor using watin

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit, watin

I could not figure out how to enter text into HTML Editor using Watin.
I tried  //`ie.TextField(Find.ById("htmlDetail_ctl06_ctl04")).TypeText("ABCD");`
But got error: Can't move focus to the control because it is invisible, not enabled, or of a type that does not accept the focus.

Can you give some example how to enter text into AJAX HTML Editor using watin please? I am not sure what to plug in frameSrc and java script from this solution - [Unit testing the MS AJAX Toolkit HTML editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939448/unit-testing-the-ms-ajax-toolkit-html-editor)

Here is html from Develper tool when click the text box:

```
<textarea class="ajax__htmleditor_htmlpanel_default" id="htmlDetail_ctl06_ctl04" style="width: 100%; display: none; height: 100%;" control="[object Object]"/>
```

Comment: <textarea class="ajax__htmleditor_htmlpanel_default" id="htmlDetail_ctl06_ctl04" style="width: 100%; display: none; height: 100%;" control="[object Object]"/>

Answer (score 1):

You can remove css or class using jQuery ( jquery-1.4.2.min.js ). like:

```
TextField notetext = iepopup.TextField(Find.ById("notetext"));  
  iepopup.Eval("$('#notetext').removeClass('note'); ");  
  iepopup.Eval("$('#notetext').css('display', 'block'); ");  
  notetext.Click();  
  notetext.TypeText(sNote);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope, it helps.

```
Link lnk = ie.Link(Find.ById("edButtonHTML"));
            ie.WaitForComplete();
            lnk.Click();
            ie.WaitForComplete();


ie.TextField(Find.ByName("content")).TypeText("I am Amit chadha");
            ie.WaitForComplete();
```